# ASP.Net Core 6 Razor Pages How do you create an Anti Permission Policy

Tags: c#, permissions, authorization, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm looking to use permission based authorization in my web app, and I want to be able to assign Roles with permissions, but also allow the admin to assign a NoPermission to a user in case there are issues.  I can get Permissions to work with claims and roles with permissions, but I seem to be struggling with getting it to work with NoPermission.

I'm adding this to my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    foreach(string permission in Permissions.AllPermissions())
    {
        options.AddPolicy(permission, policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("Permission", permission));
        options.AddPolicy($"No.{permission}", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("NoPermission", permission));
    }
});
```

Here is my Permissions.cs

```
public class Permissions
{
    public static List<string> AllPermissions()
    {
        var permissions = new List<string>();
        permissions.AddRange(Users.AllPersmissions());
        return permissions;
    }

    public static class Users
    {
        public const string View = "Permissions.Users.View";
        public const string Create = "Permissions.Users.Create";
        public const string Edit = "Permissions.Users.Edit";
        public const string Deactivate = "Permissions.Users.Deactivate";
        public const string Delete = "Permissions.Users.Delete";

        public static List<string> AllPersmissions()
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                View,
                Create,
                Edit,
                Deactivate,
                Delete
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Users.View)]` to my cshtml.cs file, and this works if the user was assigned a role or just the permission to view users, but I want to find a way to do something like `![Authorize(Policy = No.Permissions.Users.View)]` so that is they have the No version of the permission, despite the normal permission, then they are not authorized.

Comment: `.RequireAssertion(h => !h.User.HasClaim(...))`?

Comment: where would you suggest appending that?

Comment: In all of your existing policies. So that policy fails if the claim is present.

Comment: Something like this?
        options.AddPolicy(permission, policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("Permission", permission)
                .RequireAssertion(h => !h.User.HasClaim(c => 
                    c.Value.Equals(permission)
                    && c.Type.Equals("NoPermission")
                    )
                )
                );

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. That worked exactly as I wanted it too. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me was setting the ClaimType as "NoPermission" and then in my Program.cs file I included

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    foreach(string permission in Permissions.AllPermissions())
    {
        options.AddPolicy(permission, policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("Permission", permission)
                .RequireAssertion(h => !h.User.HasClaim(c => 
                    c.Value.Equals(permission)
                    && c.Type.Equals("NoPermission")
                    )
                )
       );
    }
});
```

Then the simple `[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Users.View)]` worked when added to the top of my cshtml.cs files.